# Determine the value given conditions

Tags: least-common-multiple

I am solving my exercise guide, I found this one and I answered it badly.

[image: Exercise image of]

My logic was:

Yes $x$, is multiple of $3$, then:

> $x = 3k$

And yes it is multiple of $4$, then:

> $x = 4p$

And I did not know how to do it algebraically.

Then I thought more logically and if it is divisible by $3$ and $4$, then it has to be a multiple of $12$.

It can be $60$, but also $72$, then it can not be determined, so I answered the letter **E**.

But the correct letter was **C**, so it can be obtained with both data, but how? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe, $60$ and $80$ are not included.

Comment: The statement is the original and says between whereby [60, 80] should be.

Comment: Do you know how to flip these exercises trivially? , I do not even know how to look for it on the network.

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking is correct that if it is both a multiple of $3$ and $4$ it must be a multiple of $12$.  Between should not include the endpoints, though it is used both ways.  If $60$ is excluded, answer $C$ is correct because you know it must be $72$.

Answer (score 1):

They were a bit unclear with the wording, where it mentioned "an integer between $60$ and $80$".

Instead of this, the problem could have said, "an integer being between $60$ and $80$ exclusive", or "$60<x<80$".

They probably have answer choice $C$ correct because $72$ is the only integer in the range of $60<x<80$ that is divisible by $3$ and $4$.